# How to dynamically add row in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqOLL) piece of code that should do the following:

After typing into each input field and pressing the "**Add row**" button a **new row** should be added to the end of the table. Pressing the "**Delete row**" button should remove the last row created.

At this point, when I press any of the buttons, it won't do anything.

As a mention, when I am verifying **Chromes'** Console for any **JS errors** I get this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This is the HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:lavender">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            User
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Password
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            IP
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Country
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            IP disponibility
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='user0'  placeholder='User' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='pass0' placeholder='Password' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='ip0' placeholder='IP' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='country0' placeholder='Country' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='ipDisp0' placeholder='IP Details' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
```

And this is the JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='user"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='User' class='form-control input-md'  /></td><td><input  name='pass"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Password'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='ip"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='IP'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='country"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Country'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='ipDisp"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='IP details'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });

});
```

Any ideas on what should I change in my **JS** ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are loading jQuery script?

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong. I think so. I've included bootstrap.min.js + jquerry + my script.

Comment: Probably this is any simple mistake when loading the scripts. I put your code at a fiddle and it's ok: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/bzy95wL3/2/ take a look at your browser's debug tool and check the http requests and error console.

Comment: I've got thru it. I've received that error due to the fact that i've included my script before jquery and bootstrap. Now it works flawlessly. thank you Chriss & Nacho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember jquery library must be placed first than bootstrap, maybe that would be your problem, your code is fine, here is the working fiddle using jquery 1.11.0

```
<script src="jquery.min.js">
<script src="bootstrap.min.js">
```

The fiddle [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/gLrhnqo2/

Comment: Thanks. Solved it minutes ago. The problem was that I've included myscript.js before jquerry.min.js and bootstrap.min.js. I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the Jquery script. If you select the latest version works good.